# How to declare a XQuery 1.0 while loop to generate a String by appending characters

Tags: xml, string, while-loop, xquery, transformation

In my XQuery 1.0 file I have an string as input with the same format as a xsd:duration element: PnYnMnDTnHnMnS. Where P is mandatory, n is the number of Y(ears), M(onths),etc, and T is a separator of the H(ours), M(inutes), etc.

My input cames as a string and could be incomplete, I mean, the year, month... minutes field could not appear. Then my output has to be a complete duration element where the missing fields must be filled with 0s.

Example:

P1YT1H2M50S ---> P1Y0M0DT1H2M50S

My problem is that I don't know the syntax to write correctly a while loop with local variables.

**Note: THIS CODE DOES NOT COMPILE. IT IS JUST PSEUDOCODE**

I am new in XQuery and I don't know the correct sintax to do it. My idea is to iterate over the string and check the missing fields and append the partial result to the variable that will be returned.

```
    <typ:validityPeriod>
              {
              let $input := 'P1YT1H2M50S'
              let $index := 2
              let $result := 'P'
              let $Y_read := false
              let $Months_read := false
              let $D_read := false
              let $T_read := false
              let $H_read := false
              let $Minutes_read := false
              let $S_read := false
              let $acu := ''

              while (not($S_read)){
                  let $char := xs:substring($input, $index,$index)

                  if ($char = 'Y') then
                      $Y_read := true
                      $result := fn:concat($result, $acu, 'Y')
                      $acu := ''                     
                  else if ($char = 'M') then                         
                      if (not($T_read)) then
                          $Months_read := true
                          if ($Y_read) then
                              $result := fn:concat($result, $acu, 'M')
                          else
                              $result := fn:concat($result, '0Y', $acu, 'M')
                      else
                          $Minutes_read := true
                          if (not($H_read)) then
                              $result := fn:concat($result, 'T0H')

                          $result := fn:concat($result, $acu, 'M')
                      $acu := ''                      
                  else if ($char = 'D')
                      $D_read := true                     
                      if (not($Y_read)) then
                              $result := fn:concat($result, '0Y')
                      if (not($Months_read)) then
                              $result := fn:concat($result, '0M')
                      $result := fn:concat($result, $acu, 'D')
                      $acu := ''                      
                  else if ($char = 'T') then
                      $acu := ''                      
                      if (not($Y_read)) then
                          $result := fn:concat($result, '0Y')
                      if (not($Months_read)) then
                          $result := fn:concat($result, '0M')
                      if (not($D_read)) then
                          $result := fn:concat($result, '0D')
                      $T_read = true
                      $acu := ''                      
                  else if ($char = 'H')
                      $H_read := true   
                      $acu := ''
                      <the same logic>
                  else if ($char = 'S') 
                      <the same logic>
                      $S_read := true
                  else
                       $acu := fn:concat($acu, $char)

                  $index := $index + 1
              }

              return xs:duration($result)


              }
      </typ:validityPeriod>
```

Comment: XQuery has no `while` statement. Nor mutable variables. You would need to write a separate let statement for each letter, or a recursive function. However, what do you actually want to do? Durations work fine with missing letters. `xs:duration("P1YT1H2M50S")` returns a duration.  The same duration. `xs:duration("P1Y0M0DT1H2M50S") = xs:duration("P1YT1H2M50S")` you cannot tell them apart

Comment: The specification of the output says that output must display all letters. But I found a better way using regular expressions. replace(replace(replace($input,                         "P(([0-9]+)Y)?(([0-9]+)M)?(([0-9]+)D)?(T(([0-9]+)H)?(([0-9]+)M)?(([0-9]+)S)?)?",                         "P$2Y$4M$6DT$9H$11M$13S"),                         "([A-Za-z])([A-SU-Za-su-z])","$10$2"),                         "([A-Za-z])([A-SU-Za-su-z])","$10$2")

Comment: You've written it out as very procedural pseudo-code. It's not easy to reverse engineer procedural code to declarative code; you really need to try and think in a more declarative way.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should give the right answer:

```
let $d := xs:duration('P1YT1H2M50S')
return concat('P',
  years-from-duration($d), 'Y',
  months-from-duration($d), 'M',
  days-from-duration($d), 'D',
  'T',
  hours-from-duration($d), 'H',
  minutes-from-duration($d), 'M',
  seconds-from-duration($d), 'S')
```